# How can I recreate a UIView after I have released it?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, mainwindow

In my MainWindow.xib I have many view controllers. Some of which are displayed as Modal views, and others are simply inserted. I am concerned with possible poor memory management because of the fact that I am not releasing any of the views that I create (except for in the dealloc method). However, when I do release a view my app can't bring it back up. My question is, how can I release a view to free up memory, but bring the view back when it is needed.

P.S. The only .xib I have is Mainwindow .xib. The other views were all created in interface builder as view controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Create your views programatic or use more xib files. So you can alloc init and release when you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using separate .xibs for each view controller, so you can create them using the `initWithNibName:bundle` method.

In genearl, if you're having issues or concerns of this nature, read the relevant Programming Guide documentation -- they're very good and will show you The Right Way To Do it, generally.